# UIImageView with swipe and zoom features

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I've been endlessly searching for UIImageView with swipe and zoom features but I haven't found anything to suit my requirements. I'm building a fashion ecommerce app, and I'm looking for something to display detailed images for products like on Amazon.

I know I can use a UIViewPager, but this doesn't allow for zoom. Also, I have found this library - https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController, but it does not allow for zoom and is not working for me.

Looking for something like the screenshot below :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation;

> The scroll view also handles zooming and panning of content. As the
>   user makes a pinch-in or pinch-out gesture, the scroll view adjusts
>   the offset and the scale of the content. When the gesture ends, the
>   object managing the content view should should update subviews of the
>   content as necessary. (Note that the gesture can end and a finger
>   could still be down.) While the gesture is in progress, the scroll
>   view does not send any tracking calls to the subview.
>
> The UIScrollView class can have a delegate that must adopt the
>   UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. For zooming and panning to work, the
>   delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and
>   scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:; in addition, the maximum
>   (maximumZoomScale) and minimum ( minimumZoomScale) zoom scale must be
>   different.

So you just need to use and configure `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods. Then put your images in an array and call same index as pagecontrols page for your imageview. For zooming, on your `UIScrollViewDelegate` you have to implement that method: `viewForZoomingInScrollView`:. You can also implement `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale`: optionally.
Lastly, never ever forget to set your `UIScrollView` object's `minimumZoomScale` and the `maximumZoomScale` values. (They are 1.0 by default).

I think [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) is great tutorial for you.

Answer (score 0):

The most common implementation of this task is by using `UIScrollView` with `UIImageView` as a subview. This way you can zoom your image and you can also set `UIScrollView`'s property called `pagingEnabled` to true to have pages.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve it without using UIScrollView

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pinchGesture))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func pinchGesture(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        sender.view?.transform = (sender.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale))!
        sender.scale = 1.0    
    }
}
```